# how can i found that the pod was recreate by out of limits memory

Tags: kubernetes

If a pod run out of limits memory, which define as follows:

```
   resources:
          limits:
            memory: 80Gi 
            cpu: 10
```

The kubernetes will recreate the pod but how can I found that the pod was recreate by out of limits memory?

Any logs record this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use **Heapster** for monitoring cluster resource usage.
Using a **Grafana** setup with **InfluxDB** as storage backends for Heapster gives you the CPU and Memory usage of the entire cluster, individual pods and containers.

When a Pod gets restarted due to reaching memory limit, you should see a sawtooth wave on memory graph for this pod.

More useful information about monitoring tools and how to set it up can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/).